# How do i make update function run every frame after I use OnTriggerEnter2D function in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am designing a game where once the object collides with the powerup it should wait for 10 seconds and go back to normal. I am using update function to keep count but once OnTriggerEnter function is used the update function stops running every frame. How do i counter it. Please help

```
   public class Powerup_1act : MonoBehaviour {
    //This powerup temporarily passes through all lasers

    public GameObject EffectiveTo;
    private float TimeRemaining;
    int flag=0;
    float timer=0.0f;
    public float alphalevel=.20f;
    public GameObject laserfield;
    float flag2=0f;
    float countdown=0;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        //Check the provided Collider2D parameter other to see if it is tagged "PickUp", if it is...
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false); 
            laserfield.gameObject.tag = "Temp";
            flag2 = 1;
            changealpha ();
            Debug.Log ("Active?"+gameObject.activeInHierarchy);
            StartCoroutine(Powerup());
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator Powerup()
    {
        countdown = 10f;
        while (countdown >= 0) {
            Debug.Log (timer);
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (flag2 == 1) {
//changes the alpha level between 0.2f and 0 
                if (alphalevel > 0 && flag == 0) {
                    alphalevel -= .05f;
                    changealpha ();
                } else if ((alphalevel == 0 || flag == 1) && alphalevel < .20) {
                    alphalevel += .05f;
                    changealpha ();
                    Debug.Log (alphalevel);
                    flag = 1;
                } else if (alphalevel == .20) {
                    flag = 0;
                }
                countdown-=Time.smoothDeltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }
        }
            alphalevel = 1f;
            changealpha ();
            laserfield.gameObject.tag = "Laser";
            flag2 = 0;
     }
    //heres a function to change transparency of player when a powerup is in effect
        void changealpha()
        {
            EffectiveTo.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = new Color (1f, 1f, 1f, alphalevel);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you disabling your script or the gameobject the script is attached too when it collides?

Comment: You should provide the actual code you're using. The code you're showing will not cause the behaviour you're describing. What @CNuts is saying sounds like a highly likely cause.

Comment: @Fredrik ill edit the question and add the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Coroutine`'s for your advantage:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
     StartCoroutine(PowerUp());
}

private IEnumerator PowerUp()
{
    countDown = 10f;       
    while (countDown >= 0)
    {
        // Logic during the 10 seconds

        countDown -= Time.smoothDeltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }         
}
```

Comment: If he's disabling the gameobject that has the script the coroutine will stop working too.

Comment: @CNuts Is OP talking about disabling his GameObjekt? 

Comment: Well he's saying that his update function stopped working which probably means that's what he's doing.

Comment: @CNuts Lets wait for the next Update from OP and flag it as unclear until.

Comment: @Smartis i tried that but it says "Coroutine couldnt be started because the game object 'Powerup1' is inactive"

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that when you disable the gameobject, the script that this gameobject has stop working too.

In your case when the `OnTriggerEnter2D` is fired you're setting you gameobject to false `gameObject.SetActive(false);` which means that this script will stop working because you've also placed this script on the gameobject you've just disabled.

You should move the `OnTriggerEnter2D` event on the other object that dosen't get disabled and you can disable this gameobject from there. What you do in `Update` would also be moved to that other gameobject.

[From Unity documentation:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)

> Making a GameObject inactive will disable every component, turning off any attached renderers, colliders, rigidbodies, scripts, etc... Any scripts that you have attached to the GameObject will no longer have Update() called, for example.